# How to compare NSDATA bytes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I get the file size from here:

```
 let docummentdata: NSData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(path)!
```

Now I want is if the docummentdata size is greater than 10MB. I want to do something and else something. I tried doing this:

```
 var result: Int = Int(docummentdata.length)
```

and did

```
   if docummentdata.length < 1e+7{
       print("compared") 
     }
else
{ print("not compared")
}
```

and I got something like this

**binary operator < cannot be applied to operands of type Int and Double**
how to do this compare the bytes and execute the program?

Comment: Well error is pretty obvious. You are trying to to compare an Int and a Double. WHich is not alowed.

Comment: so how can i do this?will you help here

Comment: Your indentation is... special.

Comment: In programming there is the concept of Casting, which refers to the act of converting one type to another. In your case you are trying to compare a Decimal number (with double precision) to an Integer one. This comparison requires both types oto be the same, hence a conversion. In Swift type converting numbers is easy as shown in the documentation ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html ). As shown in the answers,  ``Int(1e+3)`` will do the job.

Comment: @JavierQuevedo Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`1e+7` is a literal notation for `Double`.

Either run it through the initializer of `Int`:

```
if docummentdata.length < Int(1e+7) {
    print("compared") 
}
else {
    print("not compared")
}
```

or use an `Int` literal. You can use underscore to aid readability:

```
if docummentdata.length < 10_000_000 {
    print("compared") 
}
else {
    print("not compared")
}
```

Comment: what does those underscores indicates?

Comment: @Samjhana They don't do anything semantically. They're intended to help readability. Compare `10_000_000_000_000` to `10000000000000`